# showing alert when drag and drop matching is correct with html css js

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I followed a tutorial on internet on drag and drop,
using js function:

```
function dragUser(user, event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('User', user.id);
}
function dropUser(target, event) {
    var user = event.dataTransfer.getData('User');
    target.appendChild(document.getElementById(user)); 
}
```

and the div/id/elements I modified into this:

```
<div id="unassigned" ondrop="dropUser(this, event)" ondragenter="return false" ondragover="return false">
    Names:
    <a draggable="true" class="user" id="banana" ondragstart="dragUser(this, event)">Banana</a>
    <a draggable="true" class="user" id="newyork" ondragstart="dragUser(this, event)">New York</a> 
    <a draggable="true" class="user" id="london" ondragstart="dragUser(this, event)">London</a> 
    <a draggable="true" class="user" id="ant" ondragstart="dragUser(this, event)">Ant</a> 
    <a draggable="true" class="user" id="melon" ondragstart="dragUser(this, event)">Melon</a> 
    <a draggable="true" class="user" id="cow" ondragstart="dragUser(this, event)">Cow</a> 
</div>

<div id="fruit" ondrop="dropUser(this, event)" ondragenter="return false" ondragover="return false">
    Fruit
</div>

<div id="animal" ondrop="dropUser(this, event)" ondragenter="return false" ondragover="return false">
    Animal
</div>

<div id="city" ondrop="dropUser(this, event)" ondragenter="return false" ondragover="return false">
    City
</div>
```

to live demo I put on jsfiddle here -->
http://jsfiddle.net/skinnytotoro/njdyJ/1/

now I want to add an alert
when the sorting/ drag and drop matching is correct (like, the name belong to the correct category) there will be an alert saying **"All Matched. Welldone! :)"** (below the table or around the box)

or when one or some names belong in wrong category, there's also an alert shows text-warning like **"Almost right. Keep trying!"**

and the question is.. what code or js function I have to add to make it? (the alert thingy)

Comment: does your fiddle work with respect to the drag or drop events? gives me an error

Comment: There is an `alert()` function, but most people consider it to have poor accessibility (users find it annoying and typically close the popup immediately).  Perhaps you are looking to inject your messages into the DOM?

Comment: @AdityaSaxena it works, I assumed and tested. But i want to add extra alert or notification when the matching process is correct, is it possible?

Comment: @cimmanon yes, but by alert, i mean not the alert() like popup or something.. it's more like, a.. text below the table maybe? you know, some sort of notification/sign if you're done the matching right (like the names belong to the right category) -- I'm sorry if I didn't make it clear on my question tho

Comment: @skinnytotoro You can develope [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/848KC/1/) further...

Comment: It sounds like you may be looking for what's called a *flash message*.  In a server side language/framework, it is a message stored in the session until the next page view and then displayed on the new page.  There are some common patterns for styling this type of message (which you should be able to find now that you know what it's called)... unless you're looking for help injecting this into the DOM?

Comment: @Teemu thank you! It's almost look like what I want to achieve.. but instead of 'alert', can I make it look like this:  if (right) -> show the text "You're right" but it's not popup, more like regular text/div under the box /outside the box ?

Comment: @skinnytotoro Yes you can, it's all up to you. The fiddle was rather an example, how to find "pairs". [Instead of `alert`](http://jsfiddle.net/848KC/4/) you can execute what ever code you like...

Comment: @Teemu exactly what I want to look. I tried to "if bla bla { get element by id }" - it failed cause i don't really understand the concept of it. Now that I learn fiddle from yours it's clearer. Thank you very much!!! :D